# Add box shadow with transition effect

Tags: html, css

I'm adding a class to a div that adds a box shadow to that div. This happens dynamically via jquery. Now, when the class is added, the shadow effect is added automatically as well, without any effect. Is there a way to add some transition effect via css in this case?

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
}
```

Comment: What kind of effect? Like a fade-in?

Comment: You can add transition to the `#box`. Just search for the syntax.

Comment: Yes, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VWvua/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, simply add the `transition` (or the vendor-prefixed versions) to the CSS:

```js
$('#t').click(
  function(){
    $('#box').toggleClass('shadow');
  });
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
  -kthtml-transition: all 1s linear;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
  -kthtml-transition: all 1s linear;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="t">Toggle the 'shadow' class</button>

<div id="box">Some content in the 'box' div.</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XEWhk/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Perfect, although I think that 1s is kind of long and jerky. 0.1s or 0.2s is a nice option I think. Extremely helpful tip though, thanks!

Comment: Strange, yet, that it is so jerky (Safari 8). Usually CSS transitions act very smooth. (Thanks for the demo!) Worse even in Chrome. :-(

Comment: Is there a way to only target box shadow... not using the "all" option.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, use `box-shadow` in place of the word `all`.

Comment: Not good from a performance stand-point. Consider this technique : http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/ — Chrome Dev Tools timeline doesn't lie ;-)
Also, JQuery is overkill in this case. You just need :hover.