# Animate shadows css3?

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like a css animation which creates this:
http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/text-shadow/demo/index.html#boardgame
But the shadows drop down from the top of the screen and fall into position...is this possible? If not what's the best way to achieve this sort of effect.

```
#boardgame h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 200px auto;
    font-family: "League-Gothic", Courier;
    font-size: 200px; text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #ffd217, 20px 20px 0 #5ac7ff, 30px 30px 0 #ffd217, 40px 40px 0 #5ac7ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text shadow on a pseudo element, and animate that:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
h1#boardgame {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px auto;
    font-family: "League-Gothic", Courier;
    font-size: 200px; text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "My header";
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #ffd217, 20px 20px 0 #5ac7ff, 30px 30px 0 #ffd217, 40px 40px 0 #5ac7ff;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-animation: slide 5s;
    animation: slide 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {transform: translateY(-100%);}
    100% {transform: translateY(0%);}
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qczUs/)

### [alternate fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qczUs/1/)

Comment: Is it possible to do them one by one? Each shadow that is.

Comment: You can set another pseudo element, and animate it separately. Beyond that, you would need to duplicate the element in the HTML. All this if what you want are "shadows". If it's ok to show the full letter, then it can be done animating the y coordinate of the shadows.

Comment: added demo differently

Comment: Your second solution is perfect! I want it going in the opposite way, but I can fix that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer, it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540707/451962

```
#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -kthtml-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #D50E0E;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -kthtml-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

JS Fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XEWhk/1/).

Comment: I don't think that does quite what I want...I want the actual shadow to drop from nowhere down to its position....sort of so it looks like multiple words are dropping behind each other with a slight delay.